# MIPS Assembly Linker exercise

Tags: assembly, mips

I've been given a handout for a linker exercise. I know I need to recognize which instructions need to be modified, which addresses are involved in those instructions, and figure out the address. But in practice, I don't know what to do. Below is a picture of said exercise. Any help is appreciated.

[Linker Exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ribeP.png)

Comment: Consult your teacher if you are completely clueless. Anyway, looks like a simple matter of reading through the instructions and spotting references to symbols from the other file. E.g. in the first object you only need to fix up the two `jal check` instances and in the second one the references to `MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are good at manually encoding and decoding instructions, this will actually be pretty easy for you. Consider this line down in the bottom section that reads:

```
38:    08000014    j    50 <check+0x50>
```

Because this is a jump instruction, we must modify it as a linker would. In the end, we are trying to jump to line 50, which reads:

```
50:    8fc20000    lw v0,0(s8)
```

We must take two things into account, the **actual** address of line 50, as well as the contents of line 38, which is currently **08000014**

If I break up **08000014** into binary, I get:

```
0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0100
```

If I didn't have the luxury of already knowing that this was a jump instruction (like in this case), how would I figure out what format it is? By format, I'm referring to the MIPS Reference Data sheet, which has the **R**, **I**, and **J** instruction formats. You must take the 6 most significant bits!

```
0000 10|00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0100
```

If the 6 most significant bits were 0, then we would be in the **R** format. However, in this case, **000010** is **2** in binary. If you scan the **OPCODE / FUNCT** column in the datasheet, you'll find 2 hex on the row that corresponds to the **jump** instruction, which has a **J** format:

```
6 bit opcode | 26 bit instruction
```

If we continue to break up the rest of our binary sequence up above into groups of four:

```
0000 10|00 00|00 00|00 00|00 00|00 00|01 01|00
```

and then shift to the left two bits, we get:

```
0010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101 0000
```

Convert this back into hex to get:

```
2 0 0 0 0 0 5 0
```

Take note of the 2 least significant hex values. They read **50**. Coincidence? I think not Let's continue...

Note that the address of **check** is **00400690**, and the line that we are trying to jump to is 50 offset from that. This means that we have to do some hex addition. 400690 + 50 = **4006E0**

Take that **20000050** value and replace the 6 least significant bits with **4006E0** to get.....*drum roll*..... **204006E0**! We're almost done, we just have to reverse a step that we did previously. Take this number, and break it up into binary:

```
0010 0000 0100 0000 0000 0110 1110 0000
```

Then shift everything to the right 2 bits to get:

```
0000 1000 0001 0000 0000 0001 1011 1000
```

Then convert back to hex:

```
0 8 1 0 0 1 B 8
```

This will be the value in the contents column. As for the address for this jump instruction, we just do what we did to find the address for line 50. The jump instruction is 38 offset from **check**, so we just take 00400690 and add 38 to it to get the address of this word, which is **4006C8**